# "could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 " -- Apache Error

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

I have just installed Apache Server 2.2.15 on my machine. But, I am not able to start the server from the Start - > All Programs -> Apache HTTP 2.2 -> Control Apache Server. I can see "Running all Apache services" in the tray. I have tried following suggestions:

1 > Stop IIS and restart Apache
2 > Servername changed to localhost:80. (Query: The line in httpd.conf is

> `#ServerName localhost:80`

Isn't `#` commented line? Should I uncomment it?

What other suggestions should I try out?

Comment: I have found that Skype can hold 80 open, make sure port 80 of the localhost is not being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it can't bind to port 80, chances are you also have IIS running, and more than likely, if you're running Vista or 7, IIS's kernel component that keeps hold of port 80. It is possible to change the port IIS listens on (or just uninstall it), but it would probably be easier just to have Apache run on a different port.

Uncomment the line you pasted in your question and change the part after the colon (the port) to something of your choosing. 81 and 8080 are popular, but by no means required. Once that file has been changed and saved, restart Apache, and it should work.

Then, to get to the site that Apache is hosting, use the following URL: `http://localhost:<port>` So, for example, if you entered 8080 into the config, use `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Comment out which line? Can you please paste that line from httpd.conf ?

Comment: Oh, whoops, mis-spoke. Uncomment the line you pasted, and then change it as mentioned. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Okie I have uncommented the line `ServerName localhost:8080` and changed line `Listen 80` to `Listen 8080` . On entering http://localhost:8080, I get "It works", but not the apache confirmation page. is it working now?

Answer (score 3):

From the console run `netstat -ab` with a sufficiently priviledged user. Then you'll see what application already runs on that port. The important line to have is

```
Listen 80
```

Alternatively let it run on another port. What comes up when you connect with a browser? Then you should be able to figure out what app is stealing the port.

Answer (score 1):

[windows](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/netstat-command-windows-examples/) and [linux](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-shell-scripting/9781785881985/b5a52eb1-6b2c-4d51-a77d-729734da2ddd.xhtml) solution

**a** for all, **n** for numeric in place of symbolic, **b** for executable and **p** for program (pid):

```
windows: netstat -anb

linux: netstat -anp
```

in linux check port 80 so:

```
 sudo netstat -anp | grep :80
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it appear after upgrading products.

I checked with `sudo ss -4 -tlnp | grep 80` for listening services. Result:

```
LISTEN  0  128  0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*  users:(("nginx",pid=334,fd=6),("nginx",pid=333,fd=6),("nginx",pid=332,fd=6))
```

Such as I'm using apache2, I ran:

```
service nginx stop
service apache2 restart
```

Then it's fixed